# How to parse the html content in android using SAX PARSER

Tags: android, xml, cdata, saxparser

There is description tag in xml. It contains the html tags. I am using SAX parser in android to parse. But when it fetch data from the description tag then it does not fetch the html contents, not any tags. Then how i solve the problem of the html content parsing from the XML using SAX parser please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need wrap the description in CDATA element http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA